# Passing the result from SparseArray to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode-scanner, android-sparsearray

I am trying to scan a QR code and pass the value from the scanning result to another activity. I get the result in a SparseArray and extract the most latest scanned value. I am unable to retrieve any string in my second activity. Can anyone tel me if the results in SparseArray are of the string format? If not, how can I receive these values in my second activity in string format?

**My MainActivity**

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
    final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
    if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("barcode",barcodes.valueAt(0));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**My Receiving Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("barcode");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barcodes.valueAt(0)` is returning a `Barcode` which is implementing `Parcelable`. In your receiving Activity you should do:

```
Barcode barcode = (Barcode) intent.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
```